# Store dispatch unable to read in a const

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I would like to get the data from the dispatch back. I see in console that the call has been made (through network).

```
const getSetting = async (name) => {
  const test = await store.dispatch(Actions[name])
  console.log(test)
}
```

Comment: You can't. And maybe you shouldn't, why would you need that?

Comment: getSetting would also contain the function not the result. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Does your actions return the value ? like `return $axios.$get(...).then(response => return response)`

Comment: This looks like an antipattern